# Content assist suggests unreachable variables and functions

Tags: eclipse-cdt, content-assist

When I'm editing a source file and use content assist, then I don't want it to suggest variables/functions/etc. from other source files which I didn't include. It should only suggest things from the current file and from included headers. How can I make it so that the content assist won't suggest unreachable variables and functions? If there is no way to accomplish this, then that is frankly a ridiculous flaw for an otherwise excellent IDE.

The funny thing is that yesterday it seemed that I got it to work by moving the source files to a different folder, but today, if I don't list the source folder in "C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Locations", I get unresolved inclusions in the source file (the indexer won't even resolve standard library functions), and if I do list the folder, then I'm back to square one and content assist suggests unreachable variables/functions again.

Comment: Hi @fgsfdsfgts. I have provided an answer. Although I am not certain it really addresses your issue. If there is a reproducible completion error it can be fixed. However I suspect the issue is some additional tuning to limit further than the language restrictions. I hope you will take the time to file a [detailed feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) outlining exactly how you would have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDT does not present unreachables in code completions. The issue you are facing is the definition of unreachable AFAICT.

In C, everything that is not static is "public" and can be called from anywhere else. No declaration is even necessary (although I would recommend `-Wall -Werror`, but that is a separate discussion).

For example, consider `file.c` with contents:

```c
static void func_private1(void) {}
static void func_private2(void) {}
void func_public1(void) {}
void func_public2(void) {}
```

if you request completions for `func_` in `file.c` you get all the completions:

[image]

however, if you open another file and request completions for `func_` you only get the public ones (non-static):

[image]

Now, in the other file, if you select `func_public1`, then you can have CDT automatically add in the header file for it. You can do this with "organizing imports" <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> (Source menu -> *Organize Imports*).

You can control the behaviour of Organize Imports in the preferences (C/C++ -> Code Style -> Organize Imports)

[image]

Comment: Ok, this seems fairly reasonable. I'm using C++. With `namespace foo { int bar; }`, then outside the namespace it will give suggestions for `foo` and `foo::bar`, but not `bar`, and that's fine. But I'd appreciate an option to have the same namespace in both a header and a source file, and from a different file to only see what's in the header. It could be a feature to hide a source file from other files in the editor, or a content assist filter to exclude certain file names or formats (*.cpp), so that I can get suggestions for `foo::baz` from a header but not `foo::bar` from a source file.

Comment: The rule that you can call a function without a previous declaration is specific to C. However, CDT will propose completions for entities declared in files that are not included even for C++ code. This is by design, intended to be used together with "Add include" to *introduce* new includes. [Bug 125740](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=125740) contains some discussion of this, and tracks the addition of an option to control this behaviour.